# LUNA16 slice annotations

Tags: python

I'm processing the LUNA16 dataset. This data set has annotations.csv which contains x,y,z coordinates and the diameter of nodules related to each patient.

Usually a 3D CT scan consists of different number of slices but these annotations are provided to the scan but not to slices. So I need to annotate these slices based on the nodule location and the diameter.

But I was unable to find any resources to do this.
Cn someone help me to how to start this

PS: https://luna16.grand-challenge.org/data/ - link for the data set and the annotations.csv consists all the location with nodule diameter

Comment: So to clarify: You have your set of 3D coordinates in space, and want to infer from this which slices are affected by specific elements? Do you happen to know the exact size of each slice? Are the diameters for a perfect sphere?
Also consider providing a link to the dataset, or a description of the task.

Comment: Yes dennlinger. I posted the link for the dataset. Thank uuu